# Where to find an official copy of Microsoft Windows 7 installer?

Tags: windows-7, windows, bootable-media, installer, oem

I could not get a copy from Digital River the official distribution partner of Windows 7, as it seems to have stopped distributing windows 7.
Is there an alternative?
 - I have a product key but my hard disk with the bootable Partition has been ruined for some reason.
 - There are a lot of Malware infested Windows copies out in the bit-torrent community that are capable of sniffing out my license key and share it with the pirate community.
 - The Top google search results take me to getintopc.com which by name sounds fishy.
I do not want to shell out even more money for buying a new copy of Windows 7.

> How do I get a copy of an uncontaminated Windows 7 recovery disc ?

Comment: Can you order a recovery disc set from the  manufacturer?

Comment: The manufacturer asks me to contact the vendor after a painfully long queue wait time at their call center. The extended support cover had just expired and I considered it useless to debate about it to a poor phone support executive.

Comment: Who is the manufacturer?

Comment: Dell, I checked dell site. Good line of thought. I never looked in their website but I looked everywhere else.

Comment: See this link http://www.dell.com/support/article/us/en/04/SLN135486/EN

Answer (score 0):

You can now grab Windows 7 .isos directly from Microsoft as long as you have a valid product key. You'll be able to:

- Create a Windows 7 DVD for installation on a new hard drive
- Create a backup Windows 7 DVD
- Create a bootable USB drive with a copy of Windows 7

You just need to head over to [Microsoft Software Recovery](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-recovery) armed with your product key, and you'll be able to grab an .iso for the language you desire.

[image: Win7 Software Recovery]

Comment: Consider if you had purchased the original Win7 as an OEM (with PC) package, as last time I tried (3 weeks ago) the Windows product key detects this and halts download, and then sends you away to contact the 'manufacturer' of the PC.  :-(

Comment: Really? In spite of having a valid product key?

Comment: I feel your doubt, which was equalled by my shock at the time... as I really needed it then.   I'll try the particular P/Key in a few hours when at office, but I'm sure it was the same download option. Several years in to Win7, it is not fun starting from the beginning again! Many many updates later... aarrgghh!

Comment: Damn. Well, let me/us know. I have an OEM version on my laptop and having just found out the Digital River is no longer available, I'm concerned I'll not be able to get my hands on a Win7 iso. :(

Comment: Product key must be Retail purchase, OEM does not qualify.

Comment: [See this page](http://mirror.corenoc.de/digitalrivercontent.net/)

Comment: @Moab is that an authentic source? Domain is something else_corenoc.de_ and it ONLY **talks** about _technet_ and **Digital River**

Comment: There is no official site any more.